# Reverse Geocoding [REQUEST_DENIED] by Google Maps API

Tags: flutter, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

my VALID and ENABLED Google API Key is generating a REQUEST_DENIED response from the Maps Geocoding API when I request Reverse Geocoding. The same GOOGLE_API_KEY works perfectly on the same project with Maps Static API and Maps SDK for Android API. And YES, I have enabled the Geocoding API for billing.

I don't understand why it does not work, please help.

MY CODE:

```
static Future<String> getPlaceAddress(double lat, double lng) async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$lat,$lng&amp;key=$GOOGLE_API_KEY');

    final response = await http.get(url);
    
    return json.decode(response.body)['results'][0]['formatted_address'];
  }
```

ERROR MESSAGE ON CONSOLE:

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86...
Reloaded 1 of 960 libraries in 533ms.
D/MediaScannerConnection(10267): Scanned /data/user/0/com.example.dm_places/cache/d3bef27d-313a-4d37-8159-035faf606d438754135540374763487.jpg to null
D/EGL_emulation(10267): eglCreateContext: 0xf4525150: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
I/flutter (10267): a
I/flutter (10267): File: '/data/user/0/com.example.dm_places/app_flutter/scaled_d3bef27d-313a-4d37-8159-035faf606d438754135540374763487.jpg'
I/flutter (10267): {error_message: You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account, results: [], status: REQUEST_DENIED}
E/flutter (10267): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
E/flutter (10267): #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:260:36)
E/flutter (10267): #1      LocationHelper.getPlaceAddress (package:dm_places/helpers/location_helper.dart:19:49)
E/flutter (10267): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10267): #2      Places.addPlace (package:dm_places/providers/places.dart:21:21)
E/flutter (10267): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10267):
```

Comment: Log the url (after Uri.parse is run), copy it and curl it (or paste into a  browser).  What happens?

Comment: Maybe you restricted this API Key to your app and / or to ip address(es)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says that you are not using an API key in your request. It seems that it is because of the `amp;` in the request so the `key` parameter in the end is omitted. Remove that `amp;` and your request will work.

Answer (score 0):

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?place_id=ChIJeRpOeF67j4AR9ydy_PIzPuM&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

The above is the correct URL request for the geocoding API no need to use **&amp** in URL .